# Building a minimal twitter analytics tool

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, social-networking

Facebook provides very clear analytics of the page.

I want to build something on the similar lines on twitter.
Javascript(d3.js) can be used to draw charts and python can help me pull the data.

What I basically want are couple of features, like - your followers, conversed with you, have mentioned you, how much was your reach of each of the tweet on twitter, if you used a hash tag.

What would be a good way of implementing it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is more geared toward solving specific problems, i.e. you'll get much better results if you post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) to acquire all the information.

Followers: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids
Mentions: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline
You can use the above two in conjunction to find exactly what you are looking for.

Reach: There is really no exact way to find this. You will need to derive a formula on how you define 'reach' and once that is done the API should provide a way to do it

To get the types of hastags the user has used you can use [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) API. If you notice, the returned JSON response is highly detailed and includes information of the hastags used, which you can use to process some useful information.

Most of all, @johnthexiii is completely right. Post specific problems and you will get more specific answers :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Little new on SO so learning how to use it.

Comment: If the answer helps please mark it as the right answer by clicking the big 'check' mark :)

Comment: been there, done that :)